# Is there an "Removal Custom Field" function within Polarion Java?

Tags: javascript, polarion

Cannot remove custom fields done via **javascript** from **Polarion Live** document.

In polarion server side I have workflow script (javascript) where I have used `target.setCustomField("Field Name", variable)` in order to enable some debugging within target live document.

Problem is that I don't find API function to remove or hide those debug custom fields. Any help / workaround for this would be appreciated. Additionally it's not possible to remove fields created via Polarion UI administrator side as those are not visible in document custom fields section.

```
var target = workflowContext.getTarget();
target.setCustomField("Field name", variable);
```